# Datastructure and algorithm to detect collisions of irregular shaped moving objects

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across this interview question

> Many irregularly shaped objects are moving in random directions. Provide a data structure and algorithm to detect collisions. Remember that the number of objects is in the millions.

I am assuming that every object would have an x and y coordinate. Other assumptions are most welcome. Also a certain kind of tree should be used, I suppose, but I am clueless about the algorithm.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would expect these objects to have more than one x and y coordinate, not just one as you mention/expect. Did you post the question verbatim? I guess not, since quite some details are missing, IMO. For example, what is an _"irregular shape"_ exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have a look at the [Plane Sweep Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) or the [Bently-Ottmann Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm). It uses plane sweep to determine in `O(n log(n))` time (and `O(n)` space) the intersection of lines on a euclidian plane.

Comment: "irregularly shaped" vs. line intersection? It could be a solution in 2D but you can do better than O(n log n). In 3D it does not work.

Comment: @knivil - The algorithm can be extended to work in 3D space, that's why it's called PLANE sweep and not line sweep. The algorithms were for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely what you want is to sub-divide the plane with a space-filling-curve like a z-curve or a hilbert-curve and thus reducing the complexity of a 2D problem to a 1D problem. Look for quadtree.

Link: http://dmytry.com/texts/collision_detection_using_z_order_curve_aka_Morton_order.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this problem. First: Use bounding boxes or circles (balls in 3D). If the bounding boxes do not intersect then no further tests are needed. Second: Subdivide your space. You do not have to test every object against all other objects (that is O(n^2)). You can have an average complexity of O(n) with quadtrees.

Answer (score -2):

I guess there should be a loop which takes reference of 1 object find co-ordinates and then checks with rest of all other objects to see if there is any collision. I am not sure how good my solution is for millions of objects.
Psuedo-code:

```
For each irregular shaped object1    

int left1, left2;
int right1, right2;
int top1, top2;
int bottom1, bottom2;
bool bRet = 1; // No collision

left1 = object1->x;
right1 = object1->x + object1->width;
top1 = object1->y;
bottom1 = object1->y + object1->height;

For each irregular shaped object2
{
    left2 = object2->x;
    right2 = object2->x + object2->width;
    top2 = object2->y;
    bottom2 = object2->y + object2->height;

    if (bottom1 < top2) bRet =0;
    if (top1 > bottom2) bRet = 0;

    if (right1 < left2) bRet = 0;
    if (left1 > right2) bRet = 0;
}

return  bRet;
```

Comment: Don't know how 'irregular' these shapes are. Sounds more like rectangles.

Comment: the above algo by NatashaD is completely wrong don't follow it. You need to give a range of objects space and check if obj1 range is in obj2 rang and vice versa then collision occurred else not.